# Writing log content to custom file in golang

Tags: logging, go

I run a server which redirects the log content to a file, say "current.log" for debugging purpose which I cannot show to the user. But I got a scenario where I need to show a **specific set of logs** to the user so that they can follow up the process going on in the back end. So I tried writing another set of logs(in a custom file) for each user(one log file per user) which i need to show to the user which does not contain any secure data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use **logger mechanism** where you can **create an object** for your logger(with specific file location) and then **write logs using that objec**t. So that, the logs written **using the specific object will be redirected to that particular file**.

> The logger package that I used is "github.com/sadlil/gologger"

**Sample code:**

```
package main
import (
     "github.com/sadlil/gologger"
)

func main() {
    logger := gologger.GetLogger(gologger.FILE, "/home/user/path/user.log")
    logger.Log("Test file log")
}
```

> Note: file will be automatically created at the time of object creation

so you can create a logger object for each user dynamically(each user gets a different log file) and logs wil be redirected to that file.
The logging format will be

> [LOG] [2016-04-07 11:31:28] [main::test.go::main] [8] Test file log

Answer (score 2):

You can use **lumberjack.v2**, with it you can define a custom log file for each user.

In the following snippet I use a simple boolean to determine if the log content should be added to the log file or not for each user.

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strconv"
)

type user struct {
    id     int
    logger *log.Logger
}

func createUser(id int, logWanted bool) user {
    var l *log.Logger

    if logWanted {
        // Here the log content will be added in the user log file
        userFIle := &lumberjack.Logger{
            Filename:   "user_log_" + strconv.Itoa(id) + ".log",
            MaxSize:    250, // mb
            MaxBackups: 5,
            MaxAge:     10, // in days
        }
        l = log.New(userFIle, "User: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    } else {
        // Here the log content will go nowhere
        l = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "User: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    }
    return user{id, l}
}

func doSomething(u user) {
    u.logger.Printf("Log content: user id %v \n", u.id)
}

func main() {
    user1 := createUser(1, true)
    user2 := createUser(2, false)
    user3 := createUser(3, true)
    doSomething(user1)
    doSomething(user2)
    doSomething(user3)
}
```

This will create a new set of rolling log files for each user with the log turned **on**.

- "user_log_1.log"  for the user1
- "user_log_3.log"  for the user3
- and no log file for the user2